# How to wrap two database actions performed in two steps in a transaction from the service layer?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have a service, lets call it `MyService.cs` which exists in the business layer of my application. My application has 3 layers, business, persistence and API (regular clean architecture). A method in `MyService` needs to interact with a repository in two steps. So first it takes some input from the client, sends it to the repository and saves it to Table 1. Then it takes the newly updated data, does a bit of logic, then sends that data to the repository to be saved in Table 2. Now I want to do this atomically. That is if either of the database saves fail, do a rollback. But I don't have access to the db context from the service layer so I can't create a transaction there. How can I ensure that both of these processes either fail or succeed without access to a transaction? See flow in diagram below.

[image]

Comment: As Tyler mentions this is the purpose behind the Unit of Work. A good implementation recommend is Medhime's DbContextScope. (https://github.com/mehdime/DbContextScope) There are forks available for EF Core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you will want something like the [Unit Of Work pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application#creating-the-unit-of-work-class). The idea is you won't save until changes have been made to both repositories and therefore they are made as a part of one transaction.

Answer (score 1):

> don't have access to the db context from the service layer so I can't create a transaction there.

Well, you really *should*.  The Service layer should be responsible for specifying data shapes (queries) and orchestrating transactions.  Queries and data shapes are driven by the requirements of the service layer, and you shouldn't be modifying your repository layer to implement a change to your service layer.  The only way to do that is to make your repository layer ignorant of the particular requirements of the services.  Similarly when and whether different database reads and writes are a part of a single transaction is not soemthing your repository can or should know.

Just inject the DbContext into the service layer so you can orchestrate the transaction.  Other layers executing in the same DI Scope will resolve the *same* DbContext instance.  You can wrap the DbContext in a custom UnitOfWork wrapper if you think it's cleaner.

The other alternative is to use a [TransactionScope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?view=net-6.0) in your Service Layer and rely on that to flow an [ambient transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions#using-systemtransactions) through to your other layers.  You may need to specify the [TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscopeasyncflowoption?view=net-6.0) to make the transaction flow.

Comment: I'm confused. Clean architecture states that the service layer should be completely indepedent of the data access layer, but if I inject the dbContext into my service then the service layer would have to have a dependency on the DAL as the dbContext class exists in the DAL. To me it sounds like injecting a Unit of work through an interface is a better solution. Feel free to correct me.

Comment: Your DbContext subtype is not really a classical DAL.  It's an Entity-based repository and UnitOfWork.